# Pretty print в библиотеке demjson

Tags: python, json

Я пишу скрипт на Python, который парсит объект JS из файла. Я преобразую объект в словарь, проделываю с ним некоторые действия и сохраняю обратно в файл. Но JS объект сохраняется без нужных мне отступов. Я знаю, что это можно сделать в стандартной библиотеке json с помощью параметра indent, но в demjson его нет.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что вы получаете данные из файла и потом методом `demjson.encode` преобразуете их в объект `json`?

Comment: В https://github.com/dmeranda/demjson/blob/master/docs/demjson.txt есть фраза про параметр `compactly` (1865 строка) - это не то, что нужно?